# sessionがすぐに消えてしまう

Tags: cakephp

cakephpのsessionについて質問です。

あるページで

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$session->write('username', 'test');
```

と書き込み、別のページで

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$username = $session->read('username');
var_dump($username);
```

としたところ、Nullとなってしまいます。

何か、設定できていないのでしょうか？

バージョンは
cakephp 3.7.4
です。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

AuthセッションのタイムアウトやCSSや画像関連（favicon.ico）で実際に存在しないパス＆URLを指定しているとSessionが切れるらしいです

このサイトが参考になりませんか?
https://teratail.com/questions/158808
https://mimirswell.ggnet.co.jp/blog-241

Comment: こちらの問題、下記で解決しました。

https://qiita.com/m3m0r7/items/975e6e1032c0d809717b

ご回答ありがとうございました。